# HTML 5 datetime-local to spring mvc and convert to milliseconds

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

i am sending a post request from JSP to springMVC,

one of the variable is datetime-local

HTML Code:

```
<tr>
    <td><b>Schedule Article Date-Time:</b></td>
    <td><input type="datetime-local" id="scheduleTaskDateTime" ></td>
</tr>
```

in springMVC, my variable is :

```
private String scheduleTaskDateTime;
```

and has getter,setter methods. But the data is coming as null.

how should i send the data to springMVC controller? and how to convert to milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use JSTL tag (like `<c:out>` to print text for example) and `EL` / `SPEL` expressions. In your case, you could try something like:

```
<tr>
    <td><b>Schedule Article Date-Time:</b></td>
    <td><input type="datetime-local" id="scheduleTaskDateTime" value="${yourModelVariableNameInContext.scheduleTaskDateTime}" ></td>
</tr>
```

If you want to use a templating engine a little bit more modern and more used with Spring MVC and that allow you to keep valid (x)HTML file without visible `EL` or `SPEL` expressions or unknown tags, I'd recommend you to choose [Thymleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/) instead of JSP.